# sympy definite integral of common trigonometrical function not working as expected

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to evaluate definite integral of `cos(n*theta)` in sympy. Below is the code snippet.

```
import sympy as sp
theta = sp.symbols('theta')
n = sp.symbols('n', integer=True, nonnegative=True)
integrand = sp.cos(n*theta)
integral = sp.integrate(integrand, (theta, 0, 2*sp.pi))
print(integral)
print(integral.subs(n,0))
```

The output of the script is:

```
Piecewise((0, Ne(n, 0)), (2*pi, True))
2*pi
```

Here sympy wrongly calculates the integral as a piecewise function when `integral` is straight up zero for any integer `n`. And then upon substitution of `n=0`, it gives a non-zero answer. I want `integral` to be zero for any integer value of `n`. How to do it?

Comment: Does it have to be in sympy? Maxima is much better as an algebra scratchpad although the learning curve is a bit steep it is very powerful.

Comment: Well, to be fair, for the particular value n=0 then cos(n.theta) is identically equal to 1, so if you integrate it across [0,2.pi] you SHOULD get an answer of 2.pi. What is your problem here?

Answer (score 2):

The question says:

> I want integral to be zero for any integer value of n

The integral is not zero for `n = 0` and so the result returned by SymPy is mathematically correct regardless of you wanting something else.

If you want to exclude the `n = 0` case then you can declare `n` to be nonzero or positive rather than nonnegative:

```
In [8]: n = symbols('n', integer=True, nonzero=True)

In [9]: integrate(cos(n*theta), (theta, 0, 2*pi))
Out[9]: 0
```